# Django login redirect to wrong page

Tags: python, django

im currently working on tango with django tutorial and in part with loging in i have a problem. After i click on log in the POST is not going to rango/login but to rango/login/rango/login. Can anyone help me fix this problem and more importantly explain this behavior to me ?

user_login method in views.py

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password = password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled")
    else:
        print ('invalid login details: {0}, {1}'.format(username,password))
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied")
else:
    return render(request, 'rango/login.html', {})
```

url

```
url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name = 'login'),
```

form in html file

```
<h1>login into rango</h1> <br />
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="/rango/login/">
{% csrf_token %}
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50"/> <br       />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" size="50"/>  <br />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Thank you for your reactions !

Comment: Your login form looks ok to me - make sure you definitely have  `action="/rango/login/"`, and not `action="rango/login/"`. If you have changed the code, try restarting the server.

Comment: tbh i'd use `{% url 'namespace:sitename' %}` instead of hardcoding the url. that will work :)

Comment: unfortunately {% url 'name' %} didn't work ...